# RethinkDB: matching a string from a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

This is my table in rethinkDB

`[{"username": "row1", "some_key": ["str1", "str2"]}, {"username": "row2", "some_key": ["str3", "blah"]}, {"username": "row3", "some_key": ["blah", "blahblah"]}]`

The `field`(column) `name` can be repeated. I have a `list` `['row1', 'row2']`.

I want to run query and get all the `documents`(rows) where `name` is present in the `list`

So far i have this:

`r.db(self.PROJECT_DB).table(self.PROJECT_TABLE_PICWIZ).filter(r.row['username'] == name for name in following).limit(5).run(self.db_connection)`

`following` is the `list` here.

But this returns all the `documents`(rows)

Comment: Hey Chronix, I don't see a `following` or `username` field in your documents? Do those exist but you're just not listing them?

Comment: `following` is the list generated not related to the table anyhow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Python. I think from what I'm understanding is that you want something like this, considering `following` is just a list:

```
picwiz = r.db(self.PROJECT_DB).table(self.PROJECT_TABLE_PICWIZ)
picwiz.filter(lambda doc: r.expr(following).contains(doc['username']))\
  .limit(5)\
  .run(self.db_connection)
```

Here is what is happening:

This filter takes an anonymous function which takes your list of strings called `following` and then for every document in the table, checks if the username field is in that list via the [`contains` method](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/contains/) and returns `True` if yes, and `False` if no, adding or removing it from the final results.

It is probably also possible to replace the lambda function with the following for maybe something a bit more Pythonic and less ReQL-ish.

```
lambda doc: doc['username'] in following
```

Comment: `rethinkdb.errors.ReqlServerCompileError: Cannot use r.row in nested queries.  Use functions instead in:
r.db('picwiz').table('activity').filter(lambda var_2: r.expr(['d4N73', 'di']).contains(lambda var_1: r.row['username'])).limit(5)`

Comment: it gives me this error, yes following is just a list, and this python, thanks for the reply :)

Comment: its kinda complicated from me to understand.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain a bit more what's happening.

Comment: yeah, i understand it now, though the syntax is quite confusing to remember. thanks a lot bro. :)